# html5 canvas move element

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am working on a car racing game in HTML5 and JS. I am trying to move car using arrow keys. But it's not working.

How would you move an element in the canvas and is there any need to clear the entire canvas window before moving an element?

Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var yCoordinate = 115;
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var distance = 10;
var speed = 0.5;
var angle = 25;

var car = new Image();
car.src = "./images/p1.png";

startGame();

function startGame(){
  requestAnimationFrame(moveLane);
}

function moveLane(){
  clearCanvas();  
  drawCar();
  drawLane(10 - yCoordinate);
  drawLane(60 - yCoordinate);
  drawLane(110 - yCoordinate);
  //speed of the lane
  yCoordinate = yCoordinate - 0.4;
  //if lane crossed the bottom boundrary then reset the y co-ordinate
  if (yCoordinate <= -145){
    yCoordinate = 115;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(moveLane);
}

function drawCar(){
  context.drawImage(car, canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/4, car.width*0.4, car.height*0.13);
  setCarControls();
}

function moveCarLeft(){
  clearCanvas();
  var x = canvasWidth/2 - distance;
  context.drawImage(car, x, canvasHeight/4, car.width*0.4, car.height*0.13);
}

function drawLane(yCoordinate){
  context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  context.fillRect(canvasWidth/2, yCoordinate, 10, 20);
}

function clearCanvas(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}

function setCarControls() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
      case 37: 
        console.log('left');
        requestAnimationFrame(moveCarLeft);
        break;
      case 38:
        console.log('up');
        break;
      case 39:
        console.log('right');
        break;
      case 40:
        console.log('down');
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

Live Link: https://jsfiddle.net/jackysatpal/6j4c5dod/6/

Comment: Added full refactored code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. Check. You were not using dynamic x coordinate.

https://jsfiddle.net/6j4c5dod/7/

```
function moveCarLeft(){
 clearCanvas();
 currentX = currentX - 0.1;
 context.drawImage(car, currentX, canvasHeight/4, car.width*0.4, car.height*0.13);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my **updated demo** of how I would do it: https://jsfiddle.net/mulperi/1daahhap/

The basic idea (usually) for a game is to have an **update** -function (game loop) and a **draw** -function. 
The update function is the function you call with requestAnimationFrame() and it includes all the different things in your game that needs to be updated, like for example Player.update() etc.
The draw function on the other hand takes care of clearing the screen with ctx.clearRect() and after that does Player.draw() and stuff like that.

In my example the player movement is done by listening keydown and keyup and toggling a variable to be either true / false according to what is happening on the keyboard.
Player.update -function only checks the variable and moves if the key is pressed (ArrowLeft for example).

Below full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>World's BEstest Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid black;">

  </canvas>
    <script>
      const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
      const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

      /*
          TODO: Change player to Class based object
      */
      keyPresses = {};
      player = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        update: () => {
          if (keyPresses['ArrowLeft']) {
            player.x -= 1;
          }
          if (keyPresses['ArrowRight']) {
            player.x += 1;
          }
          if (keyPresses['ArrowUp']) {
            player.y -= 1;
          }
          if (keyPresses['ArrowDown']) {
            player.y += 1;
          }
        },
        draw: () => {
          ctx.fillStyle = "black";
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();
        }
      };

      function listenKeyboard() {
        document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown.bind(this));
      };

      function keyUp(e) {
        keyPresses[e.key] = false;
      };

      function keyDown(e) {
        console.log(e.key)
        keyPresses[e.key] = true;
      };

      /*
        Everything drawing and graphics related goes here and also
        clearing the screen before drawing each frame.
      */
      function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        player.draw();
      };

      /*
        All the update methods go here
      */
      function update() {
        draw();
        listenKeyboard();
        player.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      };

      requestAnimationFrame(update);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

So I hope this helps you to think about the structure of your game functions, makes it easier to read and understand and maybe gives you some inspiration! Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the draw and update functions. I would definitely make changes :)

Comment: @jackysatpal: Well it's not necessary, but I think it's pretty common in game development to have it structured like that :) And makes a lot of sense when you think about it to have one place where all the updates happen and one place for graphics so you don't need to search many places. If you find these comments helpful. Give a vote up :D thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have 3 options:

- Playing around with [Globalcompositeoperations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) combined with canvas save/restore.
- Using multiple canvases.

I'd really go for multiple canvases (for things that don't change like the background sky, draw it once), because save/restore can also be expensive operation.